# DB structure: two tables or one?

Tags: database-design

I have two pieces of data: 1) User and 2) Portfolio. Each user has only one portfolio. At the registration process user has to fill out the following fields:

- First name
- Last name
- Porfolio title
- Portfolio url
- Email
- Password

My DB structure at the moment looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `lastVisit` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `created` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email_UNIQUE` (`email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `Portfolio` (
  `userId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `theme` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `font` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `footer` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `isFeatured` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`userId`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url_UNIQUE` (`url`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

But now looking at the database I think there is no reason to have two separate tables. The other thing is I don't really want to mix user fields and portfolio fields.

What would you do in this case?

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you don't want to mix the fields together, it looks like you already have the optimal solution.

Comment: well, that was just my thought, I'd like to hear what others think :)

Comment: Another consideration would be how you'll query the information.  Will you always have to join the two tables in queries?

Comment: yep, every user *must have* a portfolio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scenarios in which you might want to keep them separate:

- A User can exist without having a Portfolio (do you have other types of users besides those who have portfolios?).
- A new Portfolio can be created for a User who didn't have one.
- Two users can swap portfolios (actually this would be tricky since the userid is the primary key of Portfolios).
- You might someday support multiple Portfolios per User, or multiple Users per Portfolio, or both.
- You want to manage SQL privileges to give some database user access to one table but not the other (and don't have a database that supports column-level privileges or view-level privileges).
- You want to back up the two tables separately.
- You want to monitor space consumed by the two tables separately.
- You really, really like to use `SELECT *` instead of naming columns explicitly, and you still want to be able to select each subset of columns.  And you don't want to use views for that.
- You want to get the most out of your InnoDB buffer pool for performance, and buffering smaller rows means you store more rows in the same size buffer.  Tip: declare ip as `int unsigned` instead of varchar(15).

Comment: +1 quite an extensive list of reasons why to keep those two tables separate, even if currently a fixed 1:1 relationship exists! Great work, Bill.

Answer (score 2):

a user is a person, a portfolio is not.

two tables.

Comment: Oh sure, bring logical modeling into it!  :-)

Comment: That's what I meant by saying "I don't really want to mix user fields and portfolio fields." :)

Comment: "Each user has only one portfolio"...until they don't. ;-)